# As of date queries

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to implement similar functionality to temporal tables
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx

Due to some complex business requirements, I cannot use SQL Server's temporal tables, so I'm trying to implement my own version.

Basically, I need a way to be able to determine what is the data in a specific point in time.

The table will store deltas, and a bitmask to determine what columns actually changed (changing the data to NULL is a valid scenario, that's why we need this update mask)

I do have a prototype working, but my query seems very expensive. Instead of one subquery per column, I've been trying to combine them into just 1 query (with a cursor-like behavior).

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE user_efdt
(
    user_id INT not null,
    date_effective DATE not null,
    first_name  NVARCHAR(100),
    last_name   NVARCHAR(100),
    address1    NVARCHAR(100),
    position    NVARCHAR(100),
    modified_fields VARBINARY(128) NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE user_efdt
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_user_efdt 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (user_id, date_effective);
GO
```

Data setup:

```
DECLARE @first_name_bit INT
DECLARE @last_name_bit INT
DECLARE @address1_bit INT
DECLARE @position_bit INT

SET @first_name_bit = 3
SET @last_name_bit = 4
SET @address1_bit = 5
SET @position_bit = 6


-- user john does gets added to system on 1-may-16 with first name and last name
INSERT INTO user_efdt (user_id, date_effective, first_name, last_name, address1, position, modified_fields)
VALUES (1000, '1-may-16', 'john', 'doe', null, null, CAST(POWER(2, @first_name_bit) + POWER(2, @last_name_bit) AS VARBINARY))

-- user mary ann gets added to system on 1-may-16 with first name, last name, address and position
INSERT INTO user_efdt (user_id, date_effective, first_name, last_name, address1, position, modified_fields)
VALUES (2000, '1-may-16', 'mary', 'ann', '123 main st', 'manager', CAST(POWER(2, @first_name_bit) + POWER(2, @last_name_bit) + POWER(2, @address1_bit) + POWER(2, @position_bit) AS VARBINARY))

-- john doe gets address updated on 1-apr-16
INSERT INTO user_efdt (user_id, date_effective, first_name, last_name, address1, position, modified_fields)
VALUES (1000, '1-apr-16', null, null, '456 el dorado st', null, CAST(POWER(2, @address1_bit) AS VARBINARY))

-- john doe gets position updated
INSERT INTO user_efdt (user_id, date_effective, first_name, last_name, address1, position, modified_fields)
VALUES (1000, '1-mar-16', null, null, null, 'engineer', CAST(POWER(2, @position_bit) AS VARBINARY))

-- john doe gets position updated again
INSERT INTO user_efdt (user_id, date_effective, first_name, last_name, address1, position, modified_fields)
VALUES (1000, '1-jun-16', null, null, null, 'engineer 2', CAST(POWER(2, @position_bit) AS VARBINARY))

-- john doe gets position updated to NULL (erased)
INSERT INTO user_efdt (user_id, date_effective, first_name, last_name, address1, position, modified_fields)
VALUES (1000, '1-jul-16', null, null, null, null, CAST(POWER(2, @position_bit) AS VARBINARY))

-- mary ann gets address updated
INSERT INTO user_efdt (user_id, date_effective, first_name, last_name, address1, position, modified_fields)
VALUES (2000, '1-jun-16', null, null, '1443 hoover st', null, CAST(POWER(2, @address1_bit) AS VARBINARY))

-- mary ann gets position updated
INSERT INTO user_efdt (user_id, date_effective, first_name, last_name, address1, position, modified_fields)
VALUES (2000, '1-jul-16', null, null, null, 'manager 2', CAST(POWER(2, @position_bit) AS VARBINARY))
```

Here's my version of the query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE as_of_date_query (@date DATE)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @first_name_bit INT
    DECLARE @last_name_bit INT
    DECLARE @address1_bit INT
    DECLARE @position_bit INT

    SET @first_name_bit = 3
    SET @last_name_bit = 4
    SET @address1_bit = 5
    SET @position_bit = 6

    SELECT 
        q1.date_effective, fn.val first_name, ln.val last_name, 
        addr.val address1, pos.val position
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             user_id, MAX(date_effective) date_effective 
         FROM 
             user_efdt
         WHERE 
             date_effective <= @date
         GROUP BY 
             user_id) q1
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
             user_id, 
             FIRST_VALUE(first_name) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date_effective DESC) val
         FROM 
             user_efdt
         WHERE 
             (modified_fields & POWER(2, @first_name_bit)) > 0
             AND date_effective <= @date) fn ON q1.user_id = fn.user_id
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
             user_id, 
             FIRST_VALUE(last_name) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date_effective DESC) val
         FROM 
             user_efdt
         WHERE 
             (modified_fields & POWER(2, @last_name_bit)) > 0
             AND date_effective <= @date) ln ON q1.user_id = ln.user_id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT user_id, FIRST_VALUE(address1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date_effective DESC) val
        FROM user_efdt
        WHERE (modified_fields & POWER(2, @address1_bit)) > 0
        AND date_effective <= @date
    ) addr ON q1.user_id = addr.user_id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT user_id, FIRST_VALUE(position) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date_effective DESC) val
        FROM user_efdt
        WHERE (modified_fields & POWER(2, @position_bit)) > 0
        AND date_effective <= @date
    ) pos ON q1.user_id = pos.user_id
END
```

**expected results:**

```
EXEC as_of_date_query '1-mar-16'
-- 2016-03-01   NULL    NULL    NULL    engineer

EXEC as_of_date_query '5-apr-16'
-- 2016-04-01   NULL    NULL    456 el dorado st    engineer

EXEC as_of_date_query '15-may-16'
-- 2016-05-01   john    doe 456 el dorado st    engineer
-- 2016-05-01   mary    ann 123 main st manager

EXEC as_of_date_query '5-jun-16'
-- 2016-06-01   john    doe 456 el dorado st    engineer 2
-- 2016-06-01   mary    ann 1443 hoover st  manager

EXEC as_of_date_query '1-jul-16'
-- 2016-07-01   john    doe 456 el dorado st    NULL
-- 2016-07-01   mary    ann 1443 hoover st  manager 2
```

Comment: Well, since you chose to store only deltas, the queries are expensive. If you stored the full snapshot of the row, as SQL Server 2016 temporal tables do, the queries would be trivial. It is a trade-off between speed and storage.

Comment: Storing the full snapshots is another approach we're considering. But to do that, we would have to propagate the data. 
    Example: In the example above, if we added a new record for user 1000 as of 2015-01-01 and added his first_name, we would have to propagate that first_name through all the records until 2016-05-01, when there was an entry for first_name. 
    We're afraid the logic to propagate will be quite expensive. So we're trying to figure out what's more expensive: - the query to find the proper state of the data or the propagation logic every time an entry is added/updated.

Comment: It is hard to guess which query/approach will be faster. You need to generate a large set of representative test data and compare with the stopwatch how different queries perform on your hardware.